# Use DBF database with .Net Winform application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dbf

As I am working on windows .Net Windows form application, I want to know that can we use DBF (`a FoxPro OR Dbase database file`) in .Net Windows form application ?

I want to use `DBF` as the back-end database for my winform .Net application.

Please let me know if you have any ideas/solution on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why?  It is an ancient and horribly inefficient dbase format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/dbf-foxpro), there are several ways to connect to a DBF.

Simply use the correct connection string, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Use [ODBC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/us-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection.aspx) class to access DBF files. Look at [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/dbf-foxpro) to find out the right connection string. It should be the following:

```
string dbfDirectory = @"C:\the_path_to_my_dbf_file_or_files";

using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(@"Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};DriverID=277;Dbq=" + dbfDirectory + ";"))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (OdbcCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM myDbFileFromTheUpperDirectory.dbf";

        using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an OLE DB (preferred) or ODBC driver for it, then yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the above, since .DBF files are also associated with Visual FoxPro applications, you can easily hook up with VFP's OleDB provider instead of ODBC.